# Contact form 7 cannot be submitted

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

Please look into this URL: https://www.rldrelocation.com/preliminary-application/

Whenever the form is submitted with all the given data, an error is shown that "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again." But no error found.

In the console there is the following error displayed:
Uncaught (in promise) Objectmessage: (...)get message: ƒ ()**proto**: Object

Can anyone please help me solve this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to first see if you need to update to the latest version of Contact Form 7 (which is 5.1.9) and if that doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall Contact Form 7.

Comment: The contact form 7 is already updated. Also the Wordpress is updated.